# How to test if navigation menu has all expected items?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I am using **Nightwatch.js** (Selenium/WebDriver) to test my Node.js application.

Now I would like to test if a navigation bar is existing and I also want to test if the items of the navbar are as expected.

This is how I tried to get all navigation items, but I don't know how to check the elements. Also I think this is a bit too complicated. Is this the correct way to use Nightwatch.js?

```
module.exports = {
  'navigation': function(browser) {
    var navElements = []

    function getNavElements(elements) {
      elements.value.forEach(function(element) {
        browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function(res) {
          navElements.push(res.value)
        })
      })
    }

    browser
      .url(browser.launchUrl)
      .waitForElementVisible('#nav', 10000)

    browser.expect.element('#nav').to.be.present

    browser.elements('css selector', '#nav > .item', getNavElements)
    browser.expect(navElements).to.equal(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])

    browser.end()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but this is what you missed:

- `getNavElements` is a callback, so you cannot be sure that `navElements` will be populated as expected when you test it on the next line.
- `browser.expect` is not a function. It is a simple object containing an `element` method. If you want to perform a regular test with `expect`, you will have to use [**Chai**](http://chaijs.com/) directly (Nightwatch BDD-style interface is based on this library).

Here is a minimal working code:

**HTML** (*index.html*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nightwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="item">First</li>
    <li class="item">Second</li>
    <li class="item">Third</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (*nav.js*)

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

module.exports = {
  'Navigation': function (browser) {
    var expectedNavElements = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];

    function testNavElements(elements) {
      elements.value.forEach(function (element, index) {
        browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function(res) {
          expect(res.value).to.equal(expectedNavElements[index]);
        });
      });
    }

    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000/index.html') // Change this if needed
      .waitForElementVisible('#nav', 1000);

    browser.expect.element('#nav').to.be.present;
    browser.elements('css selector', '#nav > .item', testNavElements);

    browser.end();
  }
};
```

**Commands**

1. `npm i chai` to install Chai
2. `nightwatch -t tests/nav.js` to run the test suite

---

**Note:** If Chai expectations pass, you will not get any message in console because this is not handled by Nightwatch natively. But if they do not pass, you will get an assertion error. Try to put wrong values in `expectedNavElements` and you will see...